# raster map layers squished

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel

I am new to GIS software. I've played with Google earth a bit and am familiar with downloading Canadian topographic maps. Anyways, I've been playing around with qgis. I have imported a few georefferenced tiff files and a gpx file.

I am having difficulty displaying the raster maps correctly though. The maps looks squished in the vertical dimension. If I zoom in each pixel is not square, it is a short/fat rectangle. I feel like it has to do with the coordinate system?

Does anyone have any ideas what i might do/read up on in order to figure out how to make the pixels square and the maps not stretched?

Comment: related: [Why does my map look stretched out?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81531/why-does-my-map-look-stretched-out)

Answer (score 0):

You can reproject the raster in QGIS using the Warp tool. From the menu click Raster > Projections > Warp (reproject). You will need to match the CRS to the base layer.