# Maps look very stretched in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Something a lot like this happens every time I open something up in QGIS, regardless of the file type, location, or even the projection: they are all too wide.

Note: I am using the WGS-84 "reference" system, which the program has carried by default, but have tried over a fifty-dozen different, other projections: some centered, some regional, some worldwide. But none of them happen to display properly on top of the application.

What may be causing this?

I would like to be proportional, like-say Google Maps, any generic atlas, the available visualization tools, or ArcGIS would have it.

[image]

A few people have referred me to [Why does my map look stretched out?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/81531/115). However, besides the fact that it doesn't even address the question as intended, only the WGS and a few variations thereof even show up on the map-files that I have created: as soon as I switch the layer/overall CRS over to literally anything else, the whole editor's usage-made screen goes blank, and only re-appears to pop out once I flip it back.

To clarify, and respond to @user's questions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

What happened here is that your QGIS project is set to EPSG:4326. This causes France to look that squished. To change that, click the text "EPSG:4236" in the bottom right and choose EPSG:3857 (if you prefer Google's globally super distorted Web Mercator) or EPSG:32631 / EPSG:32630 if you want to use a proper, locally perfected projection for France (that also has measurements in meters).

If that does not work, your data is bad. I assume that you started to change your data's projection definition in the layer settings. **Never do that unless you really know what you are doing.** Set it back to the original setting (or just start a new QGIS project), then it should all work just fine.